# Stand Alone SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() always return the first sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() will always return the first sheet rather than the active sheet which is most likely a bug in new sheets.

```
function testActiveSheet(){

  var ssCentral = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxx");
  var ssCentralName = ssCentral.getName();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssCentral);
  Logger.log('the ssCentralName is ' + ssCentralName);

  var currentActiveSheet = ssCentral.getActiveSheet();
  var currentActiveSheetName = currentActiveSheet.getName();

  Logger.log('the currentActiveSheetName is ' + currentActiveSheetName);
  }
```

despite the active sheet is not the first one, it still returns the first one.

Comment: Do note that your example here never changes the active `Sheet`. You call `SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet`, which changes the active `Spreadsheet`. A `Sheet` is not a `Spreadsheet`. You almost **never** want to activate either a `Sheet` or `Spreadsheet`, unless you are attempting to move or display it to the user in the UI instance that invoked the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is stand-alone and not bound to a specific spreadsheet, an active Sheet would not exist. This is *not a bug* but expected behaviour. To expand an active sheet is what a user is looking at, **not** what the script is currently working in; or as said in the official documentation, "the active sheet in a spreadsheet is the sheet that is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI."

If the script is not bound then there is no sheet being displayed to any user and therefore the function just returns the first sheet! Hope that makes sense, let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

[See here for details.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSheet())

Comment: thanks for your help @Chris . But actually, this function is called through a library loaded in a spreadsheet. So The spreadsheet is displayed and the user is on this spreadsheet when the function is called.

Comment: Okay, so this function is a part of a library attached to a bound-script not a standalone?

Comment: I got :

- 1 stand-alone script SCRIPT A that I published as an executable API named "LibraryName"
 the function here has the purpose to generate folder and files based on the information entered is a specific SHEET of the SPREADSHEET
- 1 spreadsheet SPREADSHEET containing Code - SCRIPT B
 function callActivateNewMember(){
      LibraryName.activateNewMember()
 }
when the function is called from the SPREADSHEET the function will check first if the user is in the right SHEET then selecting the first name of the member we want to activate.


check th script here

Answer (score 0):

in response to @Chris

this is the SCRIPT B

```
function callActivateNewMember(){
   LibraryName.activateNewMember()
}


 this is the standalone SCRIPT A

 function activateNewMember(){
 // DECLARE THE CURRENT ACTIVE WORKSHEET as ssCentral
 var ssCentral = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

 // check if TeamList sheet is active - if not land on Teamlist and ask to select a 
new member by his/her first name
 // goto and activate TeamList 
 var teamListSheet = ssCentral.getSheetByName('TEAM LIST');
 var teamListSheetIndex = teamListSheet.getIndex()-1;
 Logger.log('the teamListSheetIndex is ' + teamListSheetIndex);
 var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
 Logger.log('the currentSheet is ' + currentSheet);
 if(currentSheet !='TEAM LIST'){
   ssCentral.setActiveSheet(ssCentral.getSheets( 
  [teamListSheetIndex]).getRange('B5').activate();
  Logger.log('WRONG TABLE'); 
  return;
 }


 var teamListSheetLastRow = teamListSheet.getLastRow();
 var nberRows = teamListSheetLastRow-7


 // CHECK IF THE CELL IS IN THE FIRST COL AND IS NOT EMPTY
 // ------------------get the current row of the member selected
 var MemberRow  = ssCentral.getCurrentCell().getRow();
 var MemberCol  = ssCentral.getCurrentCell().getColumn();

 if(MemberRow <8 ||MemberCol>1 ){
   Logger.log('RIGHT TABLE - WRONG CELL SELECTED'); 
   return;
 }
 var memberCellValue = ssCentral.getCurrentCell().getValue(); 

 if(memberCellValue=='' ){
   Logger.log('CELL SELECTED EMPTY'); 
   return;
 }

 // VALIDATION : IS THIS MEMBER WAS ALREADY ACTIVATED
 //-----------get the column with “Reporting Activated” as header
 var repActiveCol = teamListSheet.getRange("D7").getColumn();

//-----------check if the cell of “Reporting Activated” is Y 
var checkY = teamListSheet.getRange(MemberRow, repActiveCol).getValue();
//-----------If checkY = “Y” then Alert OK
if (checkY == "Y") {
  Logger.log('MEMBER WAS ALREADY ACTIVATED'); 
  return;
}
// rest of the function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after considering the answers from Chris I decided to change the strategy
I now call the function in the standalone SCRIPT along with 2 parameters I catch from the SCRIPT bound to the Spreadsheet: ActiveSheet + ActiveCell.
then I return an error message based on the situation and display alert based on the situation.
it works now but I am not totally satisfied as I wanted to show the most limited code in the SCRIPT bound to the Spreadsheet.

thanks again to Chris for taking the time to explain to me the issue I faced. if you pass by Bali - Indonesia just let me know I'd be glad to have a coffee with you. We have a dev center here.

Answer (score 0):

If your gs script was created from within a Google Sheet you can use

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

to get the currently selected sheet